# My UnitTest works, an identical code in the Controller does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mstest

This is my first post here and i'm new to C#. 
I'm working on Microsoft Cognitive APIs, (it extract information from images), you send an HTTP request, you get an answer back from Microsoft servers. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/tutorials/csharptutorial

Here's my UnitTest (this works)

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;
using fw8.CognitiveServices;

namespace ImageTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestImagefromURL()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Test was loaded");
            Manager instance = new Manager();
            var client = instance.StartMyTask().Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("Caption: " + client.Description.Captions[0].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Output of this test is

```
Test Name:  TestImagefromURL
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:  
Trace du débogage :
Test was loaded
Task started
processing
finish
Caption: a man holding a cat
```

Calling those methods in a class library

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.Contract;
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace fw8.CognitiveServices
{
    public class Manager
    {
        public async Task<AnalysisResult> StartMyTask()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Task started");
            return await UploadAndAnalyzeImage(@"C:\Users\danie\Desktop\tot.jpg");//For testing purpose, a file from my computer
        }

        private static async Task<AnalysisResult> UploadAndAnalyzeImage(string imageFilePath)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("processing");
            VisionServiceClient VisionServiceClient = new VisionServiceClient("APIKEY");

              using (Stream imageFileStream = File.OpenRead(imageFilePath))
            {
                VisualFeature[] visualFeatures = new VisualFeature[] { VisualFeature.Adult, VisualFeature.Categories, VisualFeature.Color, VisualFeature.Description, VisualFeature.Faces, VisualFeature.ImageType, VisualFeature.Tags };
                AnalysisResult analysisResult = await VisionServiceClient.AnalyzeImageAsync(imageFileStream, visualFeatures);
                Debug.WriteLine("finish");
                return analysisResult;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now from a blank MVC Project calling same methods

```
using fw8.CognitiveServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Test()
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Test was loaded");
            Manager instance = new Manager();
            var client = instance.StartMyTask().Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("Caption: " + client.Description.Captions[0].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to those who can enlighten me! ;)

EDIT : Oups

```
code:-32000
message:No script for id: 35
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 3): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AppInsightsDomain-0cd03d5b-6ce4-4019-ae7e-b1df44463c51): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AppInsightsDomain-0cd03d5b-6ce4-4019-ae7e-b1df44463c51): Unloaded 'C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2f3c5b55\37cedeaf\assembly\dl3\94ecb1d3\002a8e73_afafd201\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll'
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Message","time":"2017-05-05T10:08:49.8412130Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"dotnet:2.3.0-41907","ai.operation.id":"OxulrgX+fP0=","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.syntheticSource":"SDKTelemetry","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-TE2K4KD","ai.operation.name":"GET /","ai.operation.parentId":"OxulrgX+fP0="},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"AI: Diagnostic message: Performance counters are unavailable when the application is running under IIS Express. Use EnableIISExpressPerformanceCounters element with a value of 'true' within the Performance Collector Module element to override this behavior."}}}
Test was loaded
Task started
processing
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2017-05-05T10:08:51.1478126Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf:2.3.0-1223","ai.internal.nodeName":"DESKTOP-TE2K4KD","ai.operation.id":"F5d9uEXsrsw=","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-TE2K4KD","ai.operation.name":"GET Home/Index","ai.operation.parentId":"F5d9uEXsrsw="},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"/vision/v1.0/analyze","id":"LikCUv5jYNQ=","data":"https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Adult,Categories,Color,Description,Faces,ImageType,Tags&subscription-key=d29a6dad583544d385357110f86d0ea4","duration":"00:00:04.4499171","resultCode":"200","success":true,"type":"Http","target":"westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
The program '[17736] chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[5428] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

EDIT 2:

Don't know if it's very subtle but actually it works when you execute those method synchronously instead of asynchronously.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Just edited my post, sorry!

Comment: @AciDroP: The deadlock is because you're [blocking on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html); the solution is to [use async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (i.e., [use `await` instead of `Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `Task<>` you should try to aim to use async all the way through to avoid situations where async/await and blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()` can lead to deadlocks.

The test can be converted to async.

```
namespace ImageTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1 {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestImagefromURL() {
            Debug.WriteLine("Test was loaded");
            var instance = new Manager();
            var client = instance.StartMyTask();
            Debug.WriteLine("Caption: " + client.Description.Captions[0].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

And Asp.Net MVC makes extensive use of async Task within its framework. Which means you are either synchronous all the way or async all the way on your actions. Mixing them can have adverse effects.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test() {
        Debug.WriteLine("Test was loaded");
        var instance = new Manager();
        var client = await instance.StartMyTask();
        var msg = "Caption: " + client.Description.Captions[0].Text;
        Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling an `async` method, you should make your controller method `async` as well. Also your method should really return *something*...

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Test was loaded");
    Manager instance = new Manager();
    var client = await instance.StartMyTask();
    return Content("Caption: " + client.Description.Captions[0].Text);
}
```